# SQL update table attribute after table join

Tags: mysql, sql

New to Sql.

I have two tables. 
client:

```
client_id  client_name status
1               JZ       NULL
2               KD       NULL
3               TF       NULL
```

and

transactions:

```
transaction_id    Amount client_id  
1                     5     1        
2                     5     2        
3                     5     3
```

I can do a join as follows:

```
SELECT client.status, client.client_id, client.client_name, SUM(transactions.Amount) AS Balance 
FROM client 
JOIN transactions ON transactions.client_id=client.client_id 
GROUP BY client.client_id 
ORDER BY client_id
```

and I get this result:

```
client_id   client_name   balance  status
1              JZ           5       NULL
2              KD           5       NULL
3              TF           5       NULL
```

However, I would like to update the value in 'status' to 'ON' if a client balance is >=0, and to 'OFF' if <0. Is it possible to do this so that it updates the 'client' table?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query has some syntax errors, but the answer to your question is basically a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT c.client_id, c.client_name, SUM(t.Amount) AS Balance,
       (CASE WHEN SUM(t.Amount) < 0 THEN 'OFF' ELSE 'ON' END) as status
FROM client c JOIN
     transactions t
     ON t.client_id = c.client_id 
GROUP BY c.client_id 
ORDER BY c.client_id, c.client_name;
```

If you want to update the value *in the table* you need an `update`.  One method that should work on most databases is:

```
update client
     set status = (select (case when sum(t.Amount) < 0 then 'OFF' else 'ON' end)
                   from transactions t
                   where t.client_id = client.client_id
                  );
```

However, I wouldn't recommend doing this.  The next transaction could invalidate the statuses.  For now, it is probably better to write the query to get the information when you need it.

Comment: If I only need the 'status' upon query, does it need to be an attribute in the original 'client' table? i.e. will the above query create the 'status', even if it does not exist in the 'client' table?   `(CASE WHEN SUM(t.Amount) < 0 THEN 'OFF' ELSE 'ON' END) as status`

Comment: @wazzahenry . . . The query calculates a column in the result set called `status`.  This calculation has nothing to do with a column called `status` in either input table.